# R package build check warning about "scales"

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, r-package, r-usethis

I am building an R package, and I am constantly getting this warning about "scales" (below). I scanned my entire code, but I can't figure out where the problem is. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

```
> checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING
  '::' or ':::' import not declared from: ‘scales’
```

There are the packages that I am importing in my package.

```
Imports: 
    tibble,
    ggplot2,
    uwot,
    dplyr,
    tidyr,
    broom,
    tidyselect, 
    ggridges,
    Boruta,
    parallel
Suggests: 
    knitr,
    rmarkdown,
    testthat,
    covr
```

Comment: You're likely using a function from the scales package using `scales::rescale()` or something of the sort that you haven't declared in your imports. The problem should disappear if you circumvent that function, or add the scales package to your imports.

Comment: @teunbrand I couldn't figure out where I am calling a function from the scales package but when I import it in my description the warning seems to go away.

Comment: Mostly ggplot2 is requiring the scales package

Comment: Agreeing with @teunbrand here - seems likely you are using a `scales` function without really knowing it's a `scales` function.  Not sure what you mean by "when I import it in my description the warning seems to go away", but if it's in your local environment, then probably you already have `scales` loaded, so no issues.  Typing `scales::` in R studio brings up the context menu - it's not too many functions to scan through and see if you recognize your code uses those.